# Efficently prune MySQL duplicate records (PHP)

Tags: php, mysql, optimization

I want to prune all duplicate entries in a MySQL database, leaving only one the earliest or latest depending on what $keep is.  I am using the following but it is very slow:

```
function pruneDuplicates($keep) {

  if($keep == 1)
    $order = "ASC";
  else if ($keep == 0)
    $order = "DESC";

  //Go through and find the duplicate hashes.  Grab the IDs that correspond to them then delete all but one ID

  $query = "SELECT HEX(hash) FROM hashes GROUP BY hash HAVING count(hash) > 1";

  $result = mysql_query($query) or die("ERROR: ".mysql_error());
  while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
      $query = "SELECT id from hashes WHERE hash = UNHEX('$row[0]') ORDER BY id $order LIMIT 1";
      $innerResult = mysql_query($query) or die("ERROR: ".mysql_error());
      $innerRow = mysql_fetch_array($innerResult);
      $query = "DELETE FROM hashes WHERE hash = UNHEX('$row[0]') AND id != $innerRow[0]";
      echo $query."<br>";
      mysql_query($query) or die("ERROR: ".mysql_error());

  }

  echo "Prune successful...";

}
```

The echo $query was for debugging.  This script took several minutes to run.  It pruned about 80,000 records (I have over 100,000 records but expect to have 1,000,000+).  I was watching mysqladmin proc stat and I see that the deletes took time.

My table description is as follows:

```
+-----------+------------+------+-----+-------------------+----------------+
| Field     | Type       | Null | Key | Default           | Extra          |
+-----------+------------+------+-----+-------------------+----------------+
| id        | int(11)    | NO   | PRI | NULL              | auto_increment |
| date      | timestamp  | NO   |     | CURRENT_TIMESTAMP |                |
| hash      | binary(16) | NO   | MUL | NULL              |                |
```

hash is an INDEX.

Comment: I suspect you could use a single `DELETE` query which said `DELETE everything with hash = 'hashtodelete' AND id != 'onetokeep'`. Note, that's pseudocode. Looping to do so would be slow.

Comment: That's essentially what I am doing, however I have to find the hashes to delete hence the select statements above it. Find duplicate hashes...For each hash get first or last ID->DELETE WHERE id != id and hash = hashtodelete...repeat

Comment: Ah, I see. Well, I think you could eliminate the second `SELECT` if you get the `hash` AND `id` values from the first. You could build a string for [`IN()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/comparison-operators.html#function_in) and then put the `id` in a [`NOT (IN ...)`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/comparison-operators.html#function_not-in) with the `id`s of what you don't want to delete.

Answer (score 0):

Deleting many rows like that will be slow no matter what you tweak to speed it up. Instead of deleting all the rows at once, try doing them in batches by including a `LIMIT` clause in your query. Additionally, make sure to run the script from a cron job instead of from a link on your website, and if you want to be really safe, either increase or disable the PHP execution time limit so you don't hit it during the deletion phase.